401 ERROR when trying send sms with groovy
I'm new in APIs
our company bought a sms panel and we should send sms to customers with jira postfunctions.
I want send sms with panel api.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong
they sent a json file like this :
    {"name": "Send",
      "event": [
        {"listen": "test",
          "script": {
            "exec": [ ""  ],
            "type": "text/javascript",
            "packages": {}}
        }
      ],
      "protocolProfileBehavior": {
        "followRedirects": true,
        "disableUrlEncoding": false,
        "disableCookies": false
      },
      "request": {
        "auth": {
          "type": "bearer",
          "bearer": [{
              "key": "token",
              "value": "{{authToken}}",
              "type": "string"
            }]
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "header": [{
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
          },
          {
            "key": "Authorization",
            "value": "Bearer"
          },
          {"key": "",
            "value": ""}
        ],
        "body": {
          "mode": "raw",
          "raw": "[\n\t{\n\t\t\"sender\": \"982000xxx\",\n\t\t\"recipient\": \"98xxxx\",\n\t\t\"body\": \"string\",\n\t\t\"customerId\": \"string\"\n\t}\n]",
          "options": {
            "raw": {
              "language": "json"
            }
          }
        },
        "url": {
          "raw": "https://www.test.com/panel/send",
          "protocol": "https",
          "host": [
            "www",
            "test",
            "com"
          ],
          "path": [
            "panel",
            "send"
          ]
        }
      },
      "response": []
    },

this is my groovy code.
I'm getting  401 error,
but i don't know what I'm doing wrong.
i searched a lot,
but i dont have any clue
def httpBuilder = new HTTPBuilder("https://www.test.com")
httpBuilder.headers['Content-Type']="application/json"
httpBuilder.headers['Authorization']=( "Bearer " + "accesstoken")
httpBuilder.request(POST,JSON) {
    uri.path="/panel/send"
   body= [sender: "XXXXX",recipient :"XXXXX",body:"Test",customerId :"1"]
 
    response.success = { resp, json ->
                log.debug  'Successful is ' +resp.status
            }
            response.failure = { resp, json ->
                log.debug  'Reader is '+resp.status
            }
         }


The Authorization header has the following structure Authorization: <scheme> <credentials>. Here scheme identifies the type of authorization and can take values ​​such as Basic, Bearer or Digest. In your case, the Authorization header should contain Bearer <access_token>, Basic is not needed here.
